# Can I simultaneously pursue separate masters and PhD degrees?

Tags: phd, masters

Can I enroll in a masters degree program via correspondence at another university while simultaneously enrolled as PhD as a regular student from University of Delhi?

Comment: Could you elaborate as to *why* you want to do that?

Comment: In 2 different fields?

Comment: Why don't you ask the University of Delhi?  They are the only ones who could give you a definitive answer.

Comment: Are either funded by anyone, and if so who?

Comment: @shan23 - This would make sense for someone wanting to pursue a PhD in their field of interest in a university while simultaneously pursuing an MBA or other more business-oriented degree elsewhere.

Answer (score 4):

The answer to the question as stated is almost certainly "yes". A correspondence degree can be pursued by anyone, regardless of occupation, and your occupation as a PhD student shouldn't affect that. Note that your department may discourage this practice, as you would effectively be holding two full-time jobs (or one full-time and one part-time, depending on how quickly you pursue the correspondence degree).

Comment: I agree if the two degrees are sufficiently distinct, but the closer they get the more problems there could be.  A PhD and an MBA should be OK, as you mention above, sounds plausible.

Answer (score 4):

I think most departments set the maximum number of hours you can work an outside job. In this case I think pursuing a second degree would count as a job. Funding agencies have even tighter rules. If you are being funded for both degrees, that would also cause major problems. Finally, most advisors would frown upon this.